# how to create a basic authentication system in node js without encryption using websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, client-server

Using node.js I have been searching around on the web for ways to create a simple client server model , in which the client requests a login authentication , whilst sending their information in json. I have seen many articles and documentation on the process , but every client server model I see looks something like this :

**server:**

```
   const WebSocket = require('ws');

    // Set up server
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

    // Wire up some logic for the connection event (when a client connects) 
    wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

      // Wire up logic for the message event (when a client sends something)
      ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
      });

      // Send a message
      ws.send('Hello client!');
    });
```

**client:**

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

code from : [Client-server communication in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407025/client-server-communication-in-node-js) (upthecreek's example)

in the above example you would send messages back and forth between client and server , but what if I wanted to send  json  as "message"(username, and password) from client to sever? How would I let the server know that: the json object is actually the login information?(from what I see in the examples there is only type 'message' in this websocket module)  I am familiar with a blocking style , where I would send messages between the client/server and wait on the response. Something like this:

**ideal server:**

```
  const WebSocket = require('ws');

    // Set up server
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

    // Wire up some logic for the connection event (when a client connects) 
    wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

      // Wire up logic for the message event (when a client sends something)
      ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        if (message) == "login"{ // if login was sent as the message type

            ws.on("credentials" , function check_credentials(json){ //wait on the user and password (blocking)
                //check credentials against database and update client
            })
        }
      });

      // Send a message
      ws.send('Hello client!');
    });
```

as you can see the server blocks and wait on the credentials of the user to match against the database. I understand this may not be a working example just the goal. Not hashing and encrypting passwords is a bad idea , but once again this is just for understanding purposes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries that do this for you, but the easiest way (imo) would be to use an event specifier in your message.

Client

```js
// do login
ws.send(JSON.stringify({t: 'login', username: 'username', password: 'password'}));
```

Server

```js
ws.on('message', function(message) {
  let data;
  try {
    data = JSON.parse(message);
  } catch {
    return;
  }
  switch(data.t) {
    case 'login': {
      // handle login and save state somewhere
      break;
    }
    case 'otherevent': {
      // Handle some other event
      break;
    }
  }
});
```